# I have a CSV file which contains two format(General and Date) for Date Column. Having issue in while working with R

Tags: r, csv

```
    > df<-read.csv("weatherdatatrail.csv")
    > header=T
    > df$Date
    [1] 01-01-1989 01-02-1989 01-03-1989 01-04-1989 01-05-1989 01-06-1989
    [7] 01-07-1989 01-08-1989 01-09-1989 01-10-1989 01-11-1989 01-12-1989
    [13] 1/13/1989  1/14/1989  1/15/1989  1/16/1989  1/17/1989  1/18/1989 
    [19] 1/19/1989  1/20/1989  1/21/1989  1/22/1989  1/23/1989  1/24/1989 
    [25] 1/25/1989  1/26/1989  1/27/1989  1/28/1989  1/29/1989  1/30/1989 
    [31] 1/31/1989 
    31 Levels: 01-01-1989 01-02-1989 01-03-1989 01-04-1989 ... 1/31/1989
```

While performing a R for the below code, it works well General format but for Date format it showing as NA..

```
   > df$Date<-as.Date(as.character(df$Date),format="%m/%d/%Y")
   > str(df)
   'data.frame':   31 obs. of  10 variables:
    $ Date             : Date, format: NA NA ...
    $ Longitude        : num  77.2 77.2 77.2 77.2 77.2 ...
    $ Latitude         : num  11.4 11.4 11.4 11.4 11.4 ...
    $ Elevation        : int  282 282 282 282 282 282 282 282 282 282 ...
    $ Max.Temperature  : num  28.2 28.5 29.6 29.3 27.9 ...
    $ Min.Temperature  : num  10.9 15.4 14.2 16.5 16.3 ...
    $ Precipitation    : num  0 0.0378 0.0893 0.2077 0.1785 ...
    $ Wind             : num  2.17 2.1 2.03 2.05 2.09 ...
    $ Relative.Humidity: num  0.559 0.705 0.718 0.779 0.781 ...
    $ Solar            : num  21 20.5 19.3 19.2 14.8 ...

    > df$Date
   [1] NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          
   [6] NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          
   [11] NA           NA           "1989-01-13" "1989-01-14" "1989-01-15"
   [16] "1989-01-16" "1989-01-17" "1989-01-18" "1989-01-19" "1989-01-20"
   [21] "1989-01-21" "1989-01-22" "1989-01-23" "1989-01-24" "1989-01-25"
   [26] "1989-01-26" "1989-01-27" "1989-01-28" "1989-01-29" "1989-01-30"
   [31] "1989-01-31"
```

I am unable to pull the perfect result.. please help me out

Comment: You should define what the "perfect" result is. Perhaps look at the `lubridate` package for working with date values.

Comment: You can try `library(lubridate); ?parse_date_time` or `mdy(c('01-01-1989', '01-02-1989', '1/15/1989'))` if the order is the same

Comment: > library(lubridate)
        > ?parse_date_time
        > parse_date_time(df$Date,c("%m/%d/%Y"))
        [1] "1989-01-01 UTC" "1989-01-02 UTC" "1989-01-03 UTC" "1989-01-04 UTC"

Comment: Can you describe the problem?

Comment: Result showing like this.. when i tried this...  
[link]> library(lubridate) > ?parse_date_time > parse_date_time(df$Date,c("%m/%d/%Y")) [1] "1989-01-01 UTC" "1989-01-02 UTC" "1989-01-03 UTC" "1989-01-04 UTC"[link]

Comment: It is a date-time format. Just wrap it with `as.Date(parse_date_time...`

Comment: actually i got the result by adding UTC ["1989-01-01 UTC"] .. this wont affect for my further steps in research work.. how to avoid this?..as i am new to R ... pls suggest me

Comment: @Nandhini I suggest you to wrap it with `as.Date` as showed in the solution posted below

Comment: Thank you akrun ... i got the result... thank you so much....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `library(lubridate)` (as commented by @MrFlick)

```
library(lubridate)
as.Date(mdy(v1))
#[1] "1989-01-01" "1989-01-02" "1989-01-15"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("01-01-1989", "01-02-1989", "1/15/1989")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change the date column to be in the same format and then convert it to a date type

```
dates <- c("01-01-1989" ,  "01-02-1989"  , "01-03-1989" , "01-04-1989" ,  "01-05-1989" , "01-06-1989" , 
           "01-07-1989" , "01-08-1989" , "01-09-1989" , "01-10-1989" ,  "01-11-1989" ,"01-12-1989" , 
           "1/13/1989" ,  "1/14/1989" , "1/15/1989"  ,"1/16/1989" ,  "1/17/1989",  "1/18/1989" , 
           "1/1/1989")

df <- data.frame(Date = dates)

df$Date <- gsub(df$Date , pattern = "-" , replacement = "/")

df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date,format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 > as.Date(parse_date_time(df$Date,c("%m/%d/%Y")))

[1] "1989-01-01" "1989-01-02" "1989-01-03" "1989-01-04" "1989-01-05"
[6] "1989-01-06" "1989-01-07" "1989-01-08" "1989-01-09" "1989-01-10"
[11] "1989-01-11" "1989-01-12" "1989-01-13" "1989-01-14" "1989-01-15"
[16] "1989-01-16" "1989-01-17" "1989-01-18" "1989-01-19" "1989-01-20"
[21] "1989-01-21" "1989-01-22" "1989-01-23" "1989-01-24" "1989-01-25"
[26] "1989-01-26" "1989-01-27" "1989-01-28" "1989-01-29" "1989-01-30"
[31] "1989-01-31"
```